# Change the default installation folder programmatically for setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

In a standard Setup project for a WinForms app I would like to **programmatically** change the default installation folder (i.e. do this when the installation happens).

Is there a way to do this? I thought using a custom Installer class might hep me with this but it seems by the time it gets to any custom actions in that class, the install folder has already been selected.

Comment: Yes what custom installer are you using.. have you looked into Creating .MSI project for your C# winForms application..

Comment: Yes--I have created an MSI project. I want to customize the default installation location **programmatically** at the time the installer is running.

Comment: I created a subclass of System.Configuration.Install.Installer

Comment: are there some Actions that you can add to this If I am not mistaken you can change the default to be what ever it is you want and or be overridden via a config file. I have done this before but it was about a year ago and I don't have the code here with me ..it's at home..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here Is my solution.
I created an additional project, which called Win msi intaller, and add the TARGETDIR property's value as an argument.

```
    static void Main()
    {
            Process setupProcess = new Process();
            string msiFilePath = @"c:\path to msi package";
            string targetDir = @"target dir path";
            setupProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"msiexec.exe /i " + msiFilePath + " TARGETDIR=\"" + targetDir + "\"";
            setupProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;    
            setupProcess.Start();
   }
```

Then you should run this program to install your msi package.